# Submit x-editable form within angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I'm using an x-editable rowform table to show some editable content. Every row contains a form with edit/delete buttons which change to submit/cancel buttons if the rowform is active.

Instead of a 'Add'-button inserting an empty new row to the table i wanted to have a modal showing a form to be filled with all the data for a new row. Till here everything works fine.

Modal opens, data could be filled in and with a click on another 'Add' button within the modal the data of the modal form is inserted into the new rowform.

The only problem: The rowform is still active and not been submitted. I need to click the 'submit' button in the table row to save changes.

**How could I submit the active rowform in the controller?**

The modal

```
    <div id="modal-addStudent" class="modal fade animate" data-backdrop="true">
      <form>
        FORM ELEMENTS

        <button type="reset" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="addTR(insert)" data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

The table

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        TDs...
        <td>
          <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-addTR" class="btn btn-xs white pull-right">
            <i class="material-icons">&#xe145;</i> Add
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="tr in trs | filter:filterTrs">
        TDs
        <td style="white-space: nowrap">
          <form editable-form name="rowform" onbeforesave="saveTR(tr)" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline pull-right" shown="inserted == tr">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
          </form>

          <div class="controls pull-right" ng-show="!rowform.$visible">
            <button class="btn white btn-xs" ng-click="rowform.$show()">
        Edit
            </button>
            <button class="btn white btn-xs" ng-click="deleteTR($index)">
        Del
            </button>
          </div>  
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

function to add TR in controller

```
    function addTR(tr) {
      vm.inserted = {
        id: vm.students.length+1,
        data: tr.data,
        isNew: true
      };

      vm.trs.unshift(vm.inserted);

      //rowform should be submitted here
    };
```

Comment: Ok I am able to add a student without keeping the table rowform visible by removing the 'shown=inserted == tr' property in the form tag.